# How to split a screen into a number of equal sized boxes all facing outwards?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a mobile site which aims to be placed in the center of a table with boxes equal to the number of players around the table.  On it are a series of scores that refer to each players score and face that player.

[image]

I think I might have to use grid in order to lay these out.  My question is whether there's an easier way built in?  I'm struggling combining both grid and `transform: rotate(90deg)`.

Without rotation:

[image]

With rotation:

[image]

Here's a code snippet:

```css
body { 
    font-family: segoe-ui_normal,Segoe UI,Segoe,Segoe WP,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "one two three six"
    "one two three six"
    "one four five six"
    "one four five six";
    grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    grid-gap: 5px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 10px;  
}

one {
  background: #707070;
  grid-area: one;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

two {
  background: #707070;
  grid-area: two;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

three {
  background: #707070;
  grid-area: three;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

four {
  background: #707070;
  grid-area: four;
}

five {
  background: #707070;
  grid-area: five;
}

six {
  background: #707070;
  grid-area: six;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<one>20</one>
<two>20</two>
<three>20</three>
<four>20</four>
<five>20</five>
<six>20</six>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D added a code snippet, apologies for forgetting :)

Comment: @Paulie_D Technically I'm using React, but it felt like using plain JS for the demo was best.  It doesn't make a difference for this example, they're identical to `<div class="one">` and replacing the CSS selectors with a `.one` instead of `one`.

Comment: If I alter the HTML to something like `<div class="one"><div class="rotate_left">20</div></div>` with the `rotate_left` class as `.rotate_left { transform: rotate(90deg);` the text doesn't seem rotated at all!  It appears to be the same orientation as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find it easier to rotate the **contents** of the divs rather than the divs themselves. Just use the divs for layout.

Theh you can leverage `writing-mode` and/or a transform as necessary.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: segoe-ui_normal, Segoe UI, Segoe, Segoe WP, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "one two three six" "one two three six" "one four five six" "one four five six";
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 5px;
}

body div {
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
  background: green;
}

.one p {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

.two p,
.three p {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
}

.five {
  grid-area: five;
}

.six {
  background: orange;
  grid-area: six;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

.six p {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <p>20</p>
</div>
<div class="two">
  <p>20</p>
</div>
<div class="three">
  <p>20</p>
</div>
<div class="four">
  <p>20</p>
</div>
<div class="five">
  <p>20</p>
</div>
<div class="six">
  <p>20</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, this was amazingly well made!  Thank you so much :)